# Python: numpy.memmap "unpleasant interactions"

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mmap

From [`numpy.memmap` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html):

> This subclass of ndarray has some unpleasant interactions with some operations, because it doesn’t quite fit properly as a subclass. An alternative to using this subclass is to create the `mmap` object yourself [...]

What are "unpleasant interactions" and what are "some operations" mentioned here?